# Let $f \in H(\mathbb{C})$ and $|f(x+iy)| \leq e^{x^2-y^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Saw this question in an old test and tried to give it a go:

> Suppose $f$ is an entire function such that $f(0) = 0$ and $|f(x+iy)| \leq e^{x^2-y^2}$. Show that $f \equiv 0$ in $\Bbb{C}$.

I usually find it quite helpful to inspect the imposed behavior at infinity and see if I can get to any conclusions.
In this case, lets suppose that $|f|$ is not bounded in $\Bbb{C}$, thus there must be some sort of singularity at infinity. Fix $x=0$ and take the limit
$$ \lim_{y\to \infty} |f(iy)| \leq \lim_{y\to \infty}e^{-y^2} = 0$$
It is evident that $f$ would have an essential singularity at infinity under our current assumptions.
I am not sure how to get some sort of a contradiction here unfortunately. I think I might be missing the point entirely.
I would appreciate greatly any hint about this problem. Care to share some ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Liouville's theorem. Observe that $x^2 - y^2$ is harmonic.

Comment: take $g(z)=e^{z^2}$ and note that $|g(x+iy)|=e^{x^2-y^2}$ so your inequality becomes $|f(z)| \le |g(z)|$ or $f/g$ constant since $g$ has no zeroes etc

Comment: @Conrad Wow nice trick! Thank you guys!

Comment: happy to be of help